# An integral expressing the resistance of a triangular region

Tags: calculus, integration, physics, triangles

Say there is an acute isosceles triangle (40,70,70 degrees) with a height of 75 units.

I would like to take the surface integral over the function $f(w,l)=w/l$ where $w$ is the width and $l$ is the length.

I'm not sure if my question makes sense, but here's how I attempted to solve this. Please let me know if I'm doing this correctly.

I know that $\sin(20^\circ )=0.5w/l$, so I have a relationship between $l$ and $w$.

Next, I want to integrate:

$$\int_0^{75} w/l = [(2 l\sin(20))/l] dl =2\sin(20)\cdot 75\quad ??$$

Click the image to see it  in more detail:

[image]

Comment: (1) Please use LaTeX to write mathematics in this site. Directions in the FAQ section, (2) I don't think using degrees is going to work very nice for trigonometric functions with derivatives/integrals. Either you introduce radians or things are going to get messy...

Comment: If $w$ and $l$ are width and length, they are not variables, so $f(w,l)$ is a constant.  The integral would just be the area times $f(w,l)$.  Then you talk about height-is this a 3D solid, like a triangular prism?  It is not at all clear what the problem is.

Comment: Ok, this problem is somewhat difficult to explain... should I edit the post? Or post a new detailed question?

Comment: @JohnAndrews, try to edit.

Comment: Here is an image of my question: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/585/9evf.jpg/

Answer (score 1):

I will use $L$ instead of $l$ to avoid confusion with $1$.  As you say, you want to integrate $\int_0^L \frac {\rho}{t \cdot W(x)}dx$ where $W(x)$ is the width at a given position.  At the end you say (using radians) $\sin \left(\frac \pi 9\right)=\frac w{2 L}$ so $W(x)=w\frac{L-x}L=2L\sin \left(\frac \pi 9\right)\frac{L-x}L=2\sin \left(\frac \pi 9\right)(L-x)$ and your integral becomes $$\int_0^L \frac {\rho}{2t\sin \left(\frac \pi 9\right)(L-x)}dx$$

Comment: The denominator does not converge when x-->L??

Comment: You are right, it diverges logarithmically.  In physical reality, you can't have a triangle go really to a point and make contact, so the upper limit should be some $L-\epsilon$ which avoids the divergence.

Comment: It seems the integral changes drastically between, say, L=74.99 and L=74.999999.

Comment: Physically, I supposed this makes sense since the smaller the constriction, the greater the effective resistance.

Comment: Yes, it will be the difference between $\log .01 =2$ and $\log .000001=-6$, times some constant.  You are right-the resistance is becoming infinite and you are getting closer and closer.